# z3py: Symbolic expressions cannot be cast to concrete Boolean values

Tags: optimization, smt, z3py

I'm having troubles to define the objective fucntion in a SMT problem with z3py.

Long story, short, I have to optimize the placing of smaller blocks inside a board that has fixed width but variable heigth.

I have an array of coordinates (represented by an array of integers of length 2) and a list of integers (representing the heigth of the block to place).

```py
    # [x,y] list of integer variables
    P = [[Int("x_%s" % (i + 1)), Int("y_%s" % (i + 1))]
         for i in range(blocks)]
    
    y = [int(b) for a, b in data[2:]]
```

I defined the objective function like this:

```py
    obj= Int(max([P[i][1] + y[i] for i in range(blocks)]))
```

It calculates the max height of the board given the starting coordinate of the blocks and their heights.
I know it could be better, but I think the problem would be the same even with a different definition.

Anyway, if I run my code, the following error occurs on the line of the objective function:

"   raise Z3Exception("Symbolic expressions cannot be cast to concrete Boolean values.")   "

While debugging I've seen that is P[i][1] that gives an error and I think it's because the program reads "y_i + 3" (for example) and they can't be added togheter.

Point is: it's obvious that the objective function depends on the variables of the problem, so how can I get rid of this error? Is there another place where I should define the objective function so it waits to have the P array instantiated before doing anything?

Full code:

```py
    from z3 import *
    from math import ceil
    
    
    width = 8
    blocks = 4
    x = [3,3,5,5]
    y = [3,5,3,5]
    
    height = ceil(sum([x[i] * y[i] for i in range(blocks)]) / width) + 1
    
    # [blocks x 2] list of integer variables
    P = [[Int("x_%s" % (i + 1)), Int("y_%s" % (i + 1))]
         for i in range(blocks)]
    
    # value/ domain constraint
    values = [And(0 <= P[i][0], P[i][0] <= width - 1, 0 <= P[i][1], P[i][1] <= height - 1)
              for i in range(blocks)]
    
    
    obj = Int(max([P[i][1] + y[i] for i in range(blocks)]))
    
    board_problem = values # other constraints I've not included for brevity
    
    o = Optimize()
    o.add(board_problem)
    o.minimize(obj)
    
    if (o.check == 'unsat'):
        print("The problem is unsatisfiable")
    else:
        print("Solved")
```

Comment: Please post your code that causes the problem that people can load directly themselves to observe the error you're seeing. The minimal the better, of course. That is, the entire program, not just selected lines out of it.

Comment: Without access to `instancestxt\ins-1.txt` file, people cannot run your program. Can you get rid of the dependence on this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're calling Python's `max` on symbolic values, which is not designed to work for symbolic expressions. Instead, define a symbolic version of max and use that:

```py
# Return maximum of a vector; error if empty
def symMax(vs):
  m = vs[0]
  for v in vs[1:]:
    m = If(v > m, v, m)
  return m

obj = symMax([P[i][1] + y[i] for i in range(blocks)])
```

With this change your program will go through and print `Solved` when run.