# Why is this formula in Z3 not correct?

Tags: python, z3py

I have the following problem with this piece of code

```
p_y = [Int("p_y_%s" % str(i+1)) for i in range(n)]
length = Int("length")
objective = length == max([p_y[i] + y[i] for i in range(n)])
```

**n** is an integer parameter,
the error is the following:

```
File "C:/Users/boezi/PycharmProjects/VLSI/SMT/src/model.py", line 29, in solve_instance
    objective = length == max([p_y[i] + y[i] for i in range(n)])
  File "C:\Users\boezi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\z3\z3.py", line 380, in __bool__
    raise Z3Exception("Symbolic expressions cannot be cast to concrete Boolean values.")
z3.z3types.Z3Exception: Symbolic expressions cannot be cast to concrete Boolean values.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? ``max`` does not create a formula, it concretely evaluates values and their relation to find a single maximum value,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [z3py: Symbolic expressions cannot be cast to concrete Boolean values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68531787/z3py-symbolic-expressions-cannot-be-cast-to-concrete-boolean-values)

Comment: This was discussed many times before, see here for the latest incarnation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68534165/936310

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this is emanating from the same assignment this person is dealing with: [z3py: Symbolic expressions cannot be cast to concrete Boolean values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68531787/z3py-symbolic-expressions-cannot-be-cast-to-concrete-boolean-values)

In any case, this is the function you want to use:

```py
# Return maximum of a vector; error if empty
def symMax(vs):
  m = vs[0]
  for v in vs[1:]:
    m = If(v > m, v, m)
  return m
```

Long story short, Python's `max` does not deal with symbolic values. You have to have your own version of symbolic max and use that instead. Too bad z3py has no way of telling that to you other than this cryptic error message you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

`max` is not a formula, but you can use this max function for your usecase:

```py
def z3_max(x, *elts):
    if not elts:
        return x
    y = z3_max(*elts)
    return If(x > y, x, y)
```

Then you can use it with `z3_max(x, y, z)`.
And if you have a list `u = [x, y, z]` of variables, you can use `z3_max(*u)`.

There might be other more elegant solutions though.

Comment: This definition seems incorrect. The recursive call doesn't refer to `elts[0]` and passes the remainder of the list which will be returned as a result; which cannot be correct. Please don't post answers without trying them out first! (Or provide example runs to show how it's used.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that, there was a [1:] that shouldn't have been there, it's fixed

Comment: I'm afraid it's still no good. Note that you're recursively calling `z3_max` and in the recursive call, you pass only one argument while your function expects two. As a guideline, please do not post solutions unless you test them first to make sure they work as expected. (If I call your current definition like `z3_max(1, [2, 3, 4])` I get a long run-time error message.

Comment: The * operator was missing on elts... Anyway, the solution you posted does the same and avoid using the star operator which is slower, so it's all good

Comment: Let's see how your "latest" fix behaves: If I run `z3_max(1, [2,3,4])` I get a long error message. If I run `z3_max(1, [])` I get an error message. Again, your definition is just **not** correct. The recursive call uses the first argument as an element in the base, but as a list in the second. The point is, do *not* post solutions unless they actually run and produce the correct value. This is not a competition, just making sure this forum contains helpful answers for people seeking info on z3/z3py.

Comment: I should have posted an example then, the input is not a list of variables. The built-in `max` function supports both

Comment: Thanks! Now this makes for a much better/helpful answer. Well-written answers are important to improve our community and your contributions are much appreciated.